# Should Angular Service change route in case of errors?

Tags: angular

Im creating a service that returns my current user from an API that will return an error (401) Unauthorized when my token is not valid anymore.

Should I use the catchError to display a message to the user and then redirect to login page or all my subscribers must catch the error and take care of it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to handle all 401 errors with global `ErrorHandler`. In the error handler check whether the error is `HttpErrorResponse` and check the response status and in case of 401 navigate to login page.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, not exactly.

What you should do is define your Authentication Strategy. Not as a code thing, but as a policy. I usually see this:

- any HTTP error in general most likely needs a Toast notification or a popup saying there's an error.
- On 400 errors: return the error. NO REDIRECT HERE. The component likely needs to highlight the errors in the bloody form.
- 401/403 (Unauthenticated/Unauthorized): the easy solution is to redirect to something like:

`this.router.navigate(['login', { returnUrl: 'whatever'} ]);`

(get the return url properly here, from activated route or something, so that login component can redirect back here after successful login)

But what if you were in the middle of an ugly form, modified all, and in the mean time your auth expired? And the thing simply redirects you and destroys 20 minutes of work on this stupid complex form?

In this case, I would rather see a popup saying that I'm unauthorized, and ideally an "log in" popup, and if not, at the very least a link to open login form in a new tab, telling the user that they need to log in in the other tab, and then come back here and try saving again.

Now, this is obviously use-case dependent and not always easy to deal with. But it is more a question of UX, then Angular itself.